# Rstan code for bayesian multivarate linear model with inverse gamma as prior for sigma

Tags: r, rstan

## Code in stan file (sp2.stan)

```
 data {
   //Data objects declared
   int<lower=0> N; //Sample size for MCMC simulations
   vector[N] y; 
   matrix[8,N] x;
 }

 parameters {
   //Model parameter objects declared
   vector[9] beta;
   real<lower=0> sigma; 
 }

 model {
   //Prior distributions 
    beta ~ normal(0,10);
   //sigma ~ gamma(5,5);use it to convert inverse gamma
     sigma ~ invgamma(5,5);
   //Likelihood 
   y ~ normal(beta[1] + beta[2:9] * x, sigma);
 }
```

## Below is R code to activate Rstan

```
dim(sp500)
[1] 455   9

xs<-as.matrix(sp500[,1:8])

# Declare data for Stan
y <- sp500$spr
x <- xs
N <- nrow(sp500)
datax <- list(N=N, x=x, y=y)
# Run Stan
mod <- stan(file ="sp2.stan", data=datax, chains=1, iter=500)
```

> Error 1:x Expression is ill formed
>
> > y ~ normal(beta[1] + beta[2:9] * **x**, sigma);
>
> Error 2:(no invgamma for sigma sampling in stan?)
>
> > Probability function must end in _lpdf or _lpmf. Found distribution family = invgamma with no 
> >     corresponding probability function invgamma_lpdf, invgamma_lpmf, or invgamma_log

Comment: I suspect your first error has something to do with the way STAN handles matrix multiplication. If x is 8 x N, and beta[2:] is a column vector then `x * beta[2:9]` seems a better idea. The other error is because you missed the underscore. From the STAN documentation: `y ~ inv_gamma(alpha, beta)`

Comment: Thank you so much. it works!